# Difference between "circumvent" and "avoid"

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between *circumvent* and *avoid*? Please provide examples.

Comment: Please provide some context or your own research - what has made you unsure about whether these words are synonyms or not? Where have you read that they are or are not? As it is I think a dictionary can tell you the differences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Circumvent* has the meaning of going around or bypassing; you may still reach your original intended destination.  *Avoid* has the rather more general meaning of not meeting, which might include not going at all.   But their meanings overlap.

Comment: And what is the difference between these two words and the `bypass`?

Comment: @some1here as verbs, I would have thought that in general use as verbs *bypass* and *circumvent* were similar, though *bypass* has specialised uses as a noun as in a road not passing through a town or as a diversion of the flow of blood around a section of a blocked artery in the heart, and *circumvention* might involve avoiding the application of some rules.